# How to Cancel a AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

What Should i Write in the Runnable Run Method to cancel the Alert.Bulider??

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Context context=this;
     ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        ad.setTitle("Warning");
        ad.setMessage("Just Testing It");

        ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        ad.setNegativeButton("Nooooo", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        ad.show();
        Handler h=new Handler();
        h.postAtTime(r, 10000);

    }
    public Runnable r=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot hide a `AlertDialog.Builder`. Instead declare the member variable `ad` as `AlertDialog`, create the AlertDialog using the builder and assign it to ad by writing `ad = builder.create()`. In the run method call `ad.cancel()`;

Comment: Not working.. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 20):

`show()` returns `AlertDialog` so make a variable as below:

```
AlertDialog dlg = ad.show();
```

and then dismiss when required -

```
dlg.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set *null* for listener, it works for me.

```
ad.setNagativeButton(yourMessage, null);
```

Hope it helps you.